# Passing a variable from a Tkinter entry field to a function in a previous class

Tags: python, class, user-interface, variables, tkinter

Repeating the usual cliche, im new to python programming and am having an issue with Tkinter interaction.
I have a working banking system which works in command line but I am trying to integrate a GUI on top of it.

Im currently struggling passing data from a Tkinter entry field to the admin login function in a previous class. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a stripped back version of what I have. Im aware the user data isnt included its passing the variables through which Im struggling with.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont
import json

class BankSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers_list = []
        self.admins_list = []

    def main_menu(self):
        #print the options you have
        print()
        print()
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("Welcome to the Python Bank System")
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("1) Admin login")
        print ("2) Customer login")
        print ("3) Quit Python Bank System")
        print (" ")
        print(app.customers_list)
        option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
        return option

    def run_main_option(self):
        loop = 1
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.main_menu()
            if choice == 1:

                name = input ("\nPlease input admin first name: ").title().rstrip() #Creates variable of admins name, removes and white space and formats as title
                password = input ("\nPlease input admin password: ").rstrip() #Creates variable of admins password, removes and white space
                msg = self.admin_login(name, password)  #Runs the 'admin_login' functions using the vadriables name and passwor
                print(msg)
            elif choice == 2:
                name = input ("\nPlease input customer first name: ").title().rstrip() #Creates variable of customers name, removes and white space and formats as title
                password = input ("\nPlease input customer password: ").rstrip() #Creates variable of customers password, removes and white space
                msg = self.customer_login(name, password)  #Runs the 'customer_login' functions using the vadriables name and password
                print(msg)
            elif choice == 3:
                loop = 0
        print ("Thank-You for stopping by the bank!")

    def admin_login(self, name, password):
        found_admin = self.search_admin_by_name(name)
        if found_admin == None:
            return ("\n The admin has not been found!\n")
        else:
            if (found_admin.check_password(password) == True):
                self.run_admin_options(found_admin)
            else:
                return ("you have input a wrong password")


    def search_admin_by_name(self):
        admin_name = admin_loginGUI.__init__.self.admin_username.get()
        found_admin = None
        for a in self.admins_list:
            name = a.get_name()
            if name == admin_name:
                found_admin = a
                break
        if found_admin == None:
            print("\nThe admin %s does not exist! Try again...\n" % admin_name)
        return found_admin

app = BankSystem()

class Login():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('270x120+100+200')
        self.master.title('Welcome to Banking Application')

        # Sets the font size and style for titles
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        self.label1=Label(self.master,text="Welcome to the Banking System", fg='red', font=self.title_font).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10)
        self.button1=Button(self.master, text="Administrator Login", fg='blue',command=self.gotoadmin_login).grid(row=6, column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=10)
        self.button2=Button(self.master, text = "Customer Login", fg = 'blue', command = self.gotocustomer_login).grid(row=7, column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=10)
        self.button3 = Button(self.master, text = "Quit Application", fg = 'blue', command = self.quit).grid(row=8, column=0,sticky=W+E,padx=10)



    def gotoadmin_login(self):
        root2=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI=admin_loginGUI(root2)

    def gotocustomer_login(self):
        root3=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI=customer_login(root3)

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class admin_loginGUI():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.admin_username=StringVar()
        self.admin_password=StringVar()

        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('450x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('Banking System Login')

        #Sets the font size and style for titles
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        self.label1=Label(self.master,text="Administrator Login", fg='red', font=self.title_font).grid(row=0,column=2)
        # -----------Username Entry Field--------------
        self.label2 = Label(self.master, text="Admin Username", fg='blue').grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.admin_username=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.admin_username)
        self.admin_username.grid(row=3, column=2)
        #-----------Password Entry Field--------------
        self.label3 = Label(self.master, text="Admin Password", fg='blue').grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.admin_password = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.admin_password, show='*')
        self.admin_password.grid(row=4, column=2)
        # -----------Buttons Field--------------
        self.button3 = Button(self.master, text="Login", fg='blue', command=app.search_admin_by_name).grid(row=8,column=2)
        self.button4 = Button(self.master, text="Back to User Menu", fg='blue', command=self.gotoadmin_menuGUI).grid(row=8,column=3)
        # self.button3 = Button(self.master, text = "Quit Application", fg = 'blue', command = self.destroy).grid(row=9, column=1)

    def admin_logincall(self):
        name=self.admin_username.get()
        password=self.admin_password.get()

        if BankSystem.search_admin_by_name(admin_loginGUI, name) == True:
            print ("True")
        else:
            ("Print False")

    def gotoadmin_menuGUI(self):
        root4=Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI=admin_menuGUI(root4)

    def myquit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


def mainGUI():

    root=Tk()
    myGUIWelcome=Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   mainGUI()
```

This is the Type Error Im recieving. 
The steps to replicate are as followed.
First click 'Admin Login' on the first window.
Next click 'Login' without entering any data.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James Garside\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: search_admin_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'admin_name'
```

Comment: what sort of problem are you having? Are you getting an error? Is it sending the wrong data? Is the program crashing? Also, why are you calling `input` in a program with a GUI?

Comment: Hi There, The code above is a minimal example. I have added the error message and the steps to replicate above.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this example is helpful.

Lets create a entry object for a Date when we initialize the the UI

```
# Date Entry
self.dateEntry           = Entry(self)
self.dateEntry["width"]  = 10
self.dateEntry.grid(row  = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
```

Then to use the data stored in the Entry object use something like this in another function.

```
targetDate = str(self.dateEntry.get())
```

I have an entire UI application on my GitHub account with multiple examples of buttons and fields that may help you. Might be worth it for you to check that out: https://github.com/Jakedjoe/Beehive

Comment: Have emailed you